# How to expose nginx in Minikube to outside

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I have deployed Nginx in minikube in AWS EC2 Instance using the below commands:

```
kubectl create deployment --image=nginx nginx-app
kubectl expose deployment nginx-app --port=80 --name=nginx-http --type=NodePort
```

It is available on NodePort: 31568
I have added this port in Security Group and able to access it on browser in another laptop with `http://EC2-PublicIP:31568`

I have many microservices which are to be exposed to outside.

Is there any way to deploy an API Gateway (Nginx or Ingress) and expose on a port and should be able to access other microservices like

```
http://EC2-PublicIp:31568/helloworld          
http://EC2-PublicIp:31568/mainpage           
http://EC2-PublicIp:31568/editorspage  
       
etc
```

I have tried adding metallb, accordingly, an IP is allocated to ingress (load balancer type). I was able to access all the microservices specified in `ingress.yaml` only inside the EC2 Instance.

This should be accessible from the outside. If yes, then how to configure it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do so since you are using Nginx.
the configuration should like something like:

#### Annotation comes to help

The "trick" is to set `annotations` to support `regexp` & `rewrite-target` with:

```yaml
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    #
    # the value can be set to  `/` or `$1` or `$2` and so on
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
```

This is the "important" annotation - the rewrite one

```
# Without a rewrite any request will return 404
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
```

---

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    #
    # This is the expected line
    # 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com # <- Set your host
    http:
      paths:
        #
        # List of desired paths
        # 
      - path: /path1
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-http
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /path2/[A-Z0-9]{3}
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-http
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thank you. I could do curl http://localhost:31578/hello, curl http://localhost:31578/welcome etc..  This gives required output   This is all within the EC2 instance.  Will I be able to do http://EC2-PublicIP:31578/hello, http://EC2-PublicIP:31578/welcome from another laptop ? How do I configure in such a way that I should be able to access these from another laptop (outside of EC2 instance) ?

Comment: Once you open a browser with real Ip and not localhost you should be to access it on any computer. You configure it with Ingress object as I showed u above

Comment: Thanks. I could access it now.

Comment: Glad to help :-)